# Filter Data with a notch filter and butterworth

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a streaming signal output to matlab. I want to filter this signal with the notch filter and butterworth filter and shortly plot this streaming filtered data, without much delay between streamed signal input and plotting the filtered data. What would be the best way of going about this? I'm not sure how to go about filtering data which is continuous. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to eventually solve my problem. Originally my code looked like this:

```
figure

% Plot known length data without filter
for i = 1:4
    subplot(4,1,i);
    plot(newData(:,1),newData(:,i+1))
end

figure

% Filter Parameters 
wo = 50/(1000/2); % notch filter frequency
bw = wo/5; 
bs = 30/(1000/2); % lower cut off frequency
[b,a] = iirnotch(wo,bw); % notch filter  
[b2,a2] = butter(4,bs,'high'); % highpass butterworth design filter

row  = length(newData);
butterData = zeros(row,4);

% Plot known length data with filter
for i = 1:4
    notchData = filter(b,a,newData(:,i+1));       
    butterData(:,i) = filter(b2,a2, notchData);
    subplot(4,1,i);
    plot(newData(:,1),butterData(:,i))
end
```

And I ended up with this after some messing around:

```
figure
h = plot(nan);

% Plot uknown length of continous data with filter
for i = 1:row
    notchData = filter(b,a,newData(1:i,2));       
    butterData(1:i,1) = filter(b2,a2, notchData);
    set(h,'XData',newData(1:i,1),'YData',butterData(1:i,1))
    drawnow
end
```

With the 'unknown' row length which can be replaced with the running time. I am now able to 'real time' filter my data. The important points that helped make this possible is to have the set function go from the beginning of the data acquisition to current data time and to force the plot to update with drawnow function. I hope this helps anyone with the same issue of attempting to real time filter there streaming/continuous data.